# Viewing a document link attached to an Item in 2013

Tags: list, hyperlink, item

How do i view the a document attached to an item in a list library, SP 2013 and is there a way to show the link to the file instead of just the paperclip image?

Comment: You can use JsLink to render the field with document url

Answer (score 0):

If I got your requirement correctly, Then you can try following solutions.

**You wanted to show document URL in a view**

**Solution 1:** Modify your view and check **Name (linked to document)** column  from the **Columns** section

[image]

**Solution 2:** Create a new column in your Library and set its value using Workflow. Value of the column will be **Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL**

[image]

In my above screenshot, I am considering `Title` column as a new column.

Finally add this new column in the view.